# change the color of the vscode search

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am configuring my VSCode, but I want to change the color of the search field. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the color of the search by including in the settings.json the following line:

`"editorWidget.background": "new color",`

Source: [Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color)

Comment: This is a self answer by OP :)  However, it needs more clarification.